# using sapply across two datasets, R

Tags: r, sapply

I'm sure there is an easy solution to this, but I'm relatively new using R, so thank you for your patience!

I have two datasets.  The first (DatA) has 44 columns and is x rows long.  The second (DatB) has 4 columns and 22 rows.  Each row in DatB corresponds to two columns in DatA.  I made a function to transform the data based on this information.  However, I have to type the function 22 times - for each of the 22 rows(see below).  22 rows are not bad, but eventually DatB will be quite large and it would be awful to have to type it all manually.

```
a <- c(13,14,15,16)
datA <- matrix(sample(a, 100, replace=TRUE), ncol=2)
datB <- matrix(a, ncol=4)

change <- function(datX, bx, wx, verX,set) {
    ifelse (datX[,bx:wx] == verX[set,1],1,
       ifelse(datX[,bx:wx] == verX[set,2],2,
          ifelse(datX[,bx:wx]==verX[set,3],3,4)))
          }

  set1 <- change(datA,1,2,datB,1)
      set2 <- change(DatA,3,4,DatB,2)
      set3 <- change(DatA,5,6,DatB,3)
      set4 <- change(DatA,7,8,DatB,4)  
      .....
      set22<- change(DatA,43,44,DatB,22)
```

Is there a way I can use sapply for this?   If it was one column in one dataset, no problem.  I would just use: `sapply(colnames(x), function(y) somefunction(x[,y]))`.  It's tricky for me though because I'm trying to loop across 2 columns in DatA and 1 row in DatB at the same time.

So to be more clear, I don't need help with my function, just in applying to the two datasets.  Although if a different function would work better for this, I would be open to it.

****edited to include sample data for set1.

Comment: If `DatB` has 4 columns, how does the last ifelse statement work? `ifelse(datX[,bx:wx]==verX[set,5],3,4))` Assumes that `verX` has at least 5 columns.

Comment: Veerendra - I've edited to include a sample for the first two columns and first row.  Pierre - the function goes as follows: if DatA does not equal any of the numbers in the first 3 columns, then the only option left is for it to equal a number in the fourth column, hence the final "IF FALSE" statement being 4.

Comment: Then why add the third `ifelse` statement if it will never be true? Are you saving it to use for bigger data frames?

Comment: Your sample data throws an error when the function is run

Comment: Oops sorry about that error.  When I put the sample in, I forgot to update the function's syntax.  Fixed now